# How can I both copy (not fill series) in excel using the fill handle while also ignoring formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, text-formatting

Using the fill handle (dragging the bottom right corner), I'd like to **copy** a cell down a column, but ignore the borders.

- Simply dragging the fill handle will "Fill" the series, eg: count up
  (see Column A below).
- Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then dragging the fill handle will keep
  the numerical values correct, but the horizontal border is then
  copied for each successive cell (see Column B below).
- Dragging the fill handle with the right mouse button (or clicking the
  small pop-up after dragging with the left mouse button) and selecting
  "Fill without formatting") fixes the border issue, but counts up (see
  Column C below).
- My desired result is shown in Column D below.

[image: Examples of fill and copy]

Edit: Below is what it looks like immediately after I drag the fill handle:

[image: fill handle drag]

You can see that the borders are copied.

**It appears that the reason for this behavior is that the horizontal border is on the *top* of the cell I'm trying to copy down, *not* on the bottom of the cell above.**

Is there a simple method for using the fill handle that doesn't involve manually removing borders each time I copy something?

Comment: Bort, did my answer help? If not, I'm happy to keep looking into it for you.

Comment: Well, it helped me realize the cause of the problem, but not so much a solution. I believe the border in my excel sheet is there from the use of the "Draw Borders" tool, which is putting a border on the inside of the cell I'm trying to copy. I am not in control of putting that border there, so I'm trying to work a solution for quick copying.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by left clicking and dragging down. It initially added the numbers, but if you click on the icon that appears at the bottom of the copied cells and select "copy cells" it worked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That does not work for me. If I drag the handle down with my left mouse button, the borders are immediately copied. Selecting "Copy cells" only fixes the numerical issue. So, I am not able to reproduce your first image. How are you dragging the fill handle without the borders being copied?

Comment: Hmmm... I tried reproducing my first image, but now the border isn't copied. But that doesn't make sense, because how else did I copy the cells down? I couldn't have started on A1 because that would just copy the header!

Comment: Oh okay, I think the issue is that in my original sheet, the border was on the TOP of the cell I wanted to copy down, NOT the bottom of the cell above.

Comment: Edit - Just saw your comment about the border being on the top of the copied cell, not the bottom of the header row. Did that solve it for you?

How did you format cell A1? I just tried this in Excel 2010 (Was using 2007 for my answer) and I was successful by doing the following:
1 - Enter "Items" in A1. Right Clicked > Format Cells > added a bottom border
2 - Dragged the fill handle down about 5 rows, which counted up.
3 - Selected "Copy Cells" as noted above and it worked. 
Perhaps there's a formatting issue?

Comment: So if the border is on the TOP of the cell I'm trying to copy, can I still accomplish the copying with the fill handle?

Comment: No, I believe the easiest way to accomplish this is to add the border to the bottom of the cell above the cell you wish to copy, if possible. Edit - There might be a way to do it with the border on top of the cell you're copying from. I'll look into it a bit more.